# TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable

Tags: python

Sorry I'm not that good at StackOverflow.

I'm trying to make a game bot with universe and i got an error saying:

```
[2018-09-14 07:28:33,723] Making new env: Taxi-v2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\pacmantest.py", line 8, in <module>
    action_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)] for ob in observation_n] 
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

The code is:

```
import gym
import universe

env = gym.make('Taxi-v2')
observation_n = env.reset()

while True:
  action_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)] for ob in observation_n] 
  observation_n, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)
  env.render()
```

Comment: Presumably `observation_n = env.reset()` causes `observation_n` to be a numpy integer, not a sequence that you can iterate through. You should `print(observation_n)`

Answer (score 1):

If you execute `print(type(observation_n))` immediately after `observation_n = env.reset()` it will likely print `'numpy.int64'`. You can only iterate on iterable objects, such as lists, single values such as int64 are not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the first two lines of your while loop. `env.reset` returns an int, while `env.step` returns a tuple.